# Search Google for domains rather than pages

Tags: google-search

I want to search for job sites in Alberta, Canada. One way to proceed is to do the usual Google search for them and then somehow loop through the results for the domains that seem to correspond to job sites.

Many of them will come from the principal job sites such as monster.com or indeed.ca. Fewer will come from lesser known sites that would still be of interest to job seekers. What I want to be able to do is to collect domains and subdomains.

For instance, and thinking procedurally, once I have encountered and noted monster.com I want to ignore subsequence occurrences of it. I want to continue to look for distinct, new domains and subdomains. Any thoughts?

I haven't found a way of doing this with any collection of Google operators. Is there a way? If that's not possible, what would be a good way of doing it?

Comment: It is possible there is no way to do it. I have been trying to solve essentially the same problem and the few responses fail to understand the problem. It seems all the attention is on the input search string statistics.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me!

Answer (score 3):

What about [related:jobs.alberta.ca](http://www.google.com/search?q=related%3ajobs.alberta.ca)?

Comment: This is not what was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this [site:ca jobs alberta](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aca+jobs+alberta)?

Turning Instant Search on will get rid of the redundant domains (it's okay to hit enter and get finer results). Here are the Instant Search results:

[image: results]

[image: page2]

Comment: Thanks for responding, Louis. I need to clarify. 

When you enter a query like the one you suggest Google returns a collection of pages. Many of them will come from the principal job sites such as monster.com or indeed.ca. Fewer will come from lesser known sites that would still be of interest to job seekers. What I want to be able to do is to collect domains and subdomains. For instance, and thinking procedurally, once I have encountered and noted monster.com I want to ignore subsequence occurrences of it. I want to continue to look for distinct, new domains and subdomains.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Google seems to treat us differently. On my end the query behaves according to what you desire. I'll add an image of my results.

Comment: This is not what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do it using Google XML API since there are no API that filters the hits in the way that you want.  That is not to say that you cannot bring back ALL the hits and filter them yourself.  If you take this verbose approach, I would look into seeing what was involved to have your filter process run on their server.

Answer (score 0):

As a bunch of answers for other [google-search] tags point out you can remove sites via -site:monster.com .  [prevent-many-results-from-same-domain-in-google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30015/prevent-many-results-from-same-domain-in-google-search) You could try searching for the domains by [find-pages-containing-the-most-proper-nouns](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130121/i-want-search-engine-to-find-sites-containing-the-most-the-rare-proper-nouns-i-s/138549) instead of Google's base similarity and relevance to see is someone made a list directory for you already.