# Prevent many results from same domain in Google search

Tags: google-search

A few months ago Google changed their default behavior so that there is no limit to the number of results listed from the same domain.  Previously, it would list one or two results and provide a link for more results from the same domain.

I'm looking for any way to restore something similar to the old behavior.  Anything that will limit the results from any single domain on a single page of results to something reasonable (eg 3 or less) will work.  Maybe a Firefox extension or greasemonkey script.

I figured when this switch was first made that it was so annoying that it would be fixed (either by Google or a third party extension) quickly.  However, after months the only thing I find when searching about it are people complaining, and a lot of [SEO people complaining about it hurting their rankings](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-same-result-same-page-15287.html).

To be clear: I don't want to ban certain (spamy) domains.  Rather, I just want to limit the number of results from any one domain displayed on one page.

Here are some examples.  I tested these on a new install of Chromium.  I turned off safe search and instant results and set results per page to 100.  It seems to be made much worse by setting the results per page higher.

Examples:

[Results 2-9 from freebsd.org](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&safe=off&q=s3fs%20set%20port)

[First 15 results from mpd.wikia.com](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&safe=off&q=mpd%20song%20change)

[First 22 results form stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&safe=off&q=javascript%20regex%20right%20to%20left)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I wrote a [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) script to fix this, http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/141480.

I don't have much [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) experience, but it seems to work well enough. I'm still amazed no one else had written something like this yet. It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude a domain if it's showing too many results and you don't want any of them.

For example, this will skip Stackoverflow in your search,

```
Google Search: javascript regex right to left -site:stackoverflow.com
```

You can add multiple `-site:` excludes...

```
Google Search: hugo awards 2012 -site:www.thehugoawards.org -site:chicon.org
```

I used that once to see who was talking about them `:-)`

Comment: While useful, this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Al, well it does give him a strong-direction while there appears darkness all around (as in, no other answers). But, I have problems with your down-vote.

Comment: Votes are anonymous. One shouldn't assume.

Comment: Hmmm, and I made a typo when trying to write that; I _don't_ have problems with the down-vote.